# zend_loader_autoloader does not seem to load abstract class

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-autoloader

I am getting a grip on Zend_Autoload but a non-zend class I have is not loading when extended.

The autoloader is initialized like so:

```
 // Initialise Autoloader
 $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
 $autoloader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(true);
 $autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
 $autoloader->registerNamespace('lib_');
 }
```

It all works fine with other classes.  Is it required to load abstract class files and implemented interfaces manually beforehand?

Comment: The auto loader should load all class / interface files on request. Can you describe what's not working? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Just a silent fail.  I am doing a console script that uses a couple of Zend's classes, I tried to implement a viable error handling solution using exception handling and multiple catch block at the end of my script, but a lot of errors don't show up even though error_reporting is set to -1 ( shows all ) and display_error = 1.

Comment: I posted another question concerning the error handling related to this issue at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5739615/604259.

Comment: does it load non abstract classes because you specify just the abstract ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_loader_autoloader actually **does** load abstract classes, *idem for any interface a class may implement*. Sweet.

A couple of debugging calls straight in the Zend_Loader class quickly indicated my problem:
My file was named AbstractTableFetch.php , the class was called FetchTable.

The autoloader obviously will only works if the filename and class name are the same.

Comment: Yup, that's how it works. It directly maps class names to a filesystem path