# Troubleshooting Zend Framework Autoloader

Tags: php, zend-framework, namespaces, autoload

Can anyone recommend a way to troubleshoot why a particular class isn't being loaded by the autoloader? I'm using namespace autoloading as such:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace('\Xyz');

if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development') {
    $loader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(false);
}
```

Some classes in the Xyz namespace are being loaded while others aren't. In the place where the error is being thrown about the class not being found, I can add a `require_once` to the class file and it works fine.

I've seen this question: [zend_loader_autoloader does not seem to load abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739325/zend-loader-autoloader-does-not-seem-to-load-abstract-class) where the poster debugged Zend_Loader, but when I do so, the only classes I see it autoloading are Zend_ and ZendX_ classes. Where do other registered namespaces get loaded, and is there a way to dump all of the classes that are loaded at a given point in my code?

Comment: I'm not really sure so I post this as a comment but in the namespace you should use the '_' and not the '\'.

Comment: Thanks Aurelio, but according to this page, as of ZF 1.10, true PHP namespace autoloading is supported: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html See the "Note: Loading Classes from PHP Namespaces" section. Also, some of my classes are successfully loading this way. I just need to figure out why some other classes are not.

Comment: Some random 'maybe' problems: 1) remove the leading \. As far as I know it is not required. 2) Namespace/Class does not match the directory structure. 3) Add a leading \ when referring to the object: 'new \My\Test();' Debugging the autoloader is quite difficult as all autoloaders relay on the php-function which isn't that talky.

Comment: Fge, I've tried without the leading slash in the autoloader namespace and it doesn't seem to work. I get errors because it's trying to load the class relative to the current namespace where the class is instantiated. I've checked the directory structure/class name multiple times, but can't see any discrepancy in the structure vs. namespace. I tried adding the full namespace (including leading \) to the beginning of the class name when I'm instantiating it, but I get the same class not found error. In this case, again, if I add the `require_once` it works fine. I'm stumped.

Comment: I take it you have already tried `$loader->registerNamespace('Xyz_');
`

Comment: I had this problem as well. Solved this by adding a leading \ before classes that are loaded from an other namespace (indicating I'm going from the "root namespace"): new \My\Test();

Comment: @vascowhite, the underscore isn't necessary unless you are using userland namepacing where underscores in class names are used as namespace delimiters.

Comment: @Fge Thanks for the advice. I did end up removing the leading slash in my `$loader->registerNamespace('\Xyz');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out what my problem was. I was finally able to track it down by stepping through the autoloader line by line. What happened was when I was converting my classes from using "userland" namespaces (Xyz_My_ClassName) to use a PHP namespace definition at the top of each class, I missed changing my import declarations, so the autoloader was looking for the old class name. Thanks to everyone who helped me track this down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify to application.ini

1) `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Xyz"`

2) Be shore that you have the `Xyz` folder in your library .

3) Create a file like `test.php` in `Xyz`

4) In `test.php` you need to have `class Xyz_test extends ....`

5) In index controler try to `$var = new Xzy_test();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply; however, specifying autoloaderNamespaces[] in the application.ini I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) is just another way of doing the same thing I'm doing with `$loader->registerNamespace();`. 

Also, when using true PHP namespacing, rather than "userland" namespacing (Xyz_My_Class), it is not required to name your classes with underscores. In other words, I'd have a directory structure and namespace of Xyz\My and a file path of Xyz\My\ClassName.php. Then I can instantiate it as `new ClassName()` as long as I've imported the namespace in the file I'm instantiating it in.